# How to rewrite URL with Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

In Codeigniter how to rewrite URL?

I already tried to change the route like this :

```
$route['backend/user/profile/(:num)/'] = 'backend/user/profile/$1/$2';
```

But still nothing could change.

```
I have url : http://pa.ig/backend/user/profile/204/disabled
Url Expected : http://pa.ig/backend/user/profile/204
```

Please help me to fix this.
Thank you.

Comment: $route['backend/user/profile/(:num)/']   to $route['backend/user/profile/(:num)/(:string)']

Comment: @dimas you have $1/$2,it means two params.One is (:num) while other is missing.

Answer (score 1):

if your last param is string you can use `(:any)` for that

```
$route['backend/user/profile/(:num)/(:any)']  = 'backend/user/profile/$1';
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

if the second parameter is optional, you can try this

in your **routes**:

```
$route['backend/user/profile/(:num)'] = 'backend/user/profile/$1';
$route['backend/user/profile/(:num)/(:string)'] = 'backend/user/profile/$1/$2';
```

and in your **controller**, give default value for the second parameter of your function

```
public function profile( $id , $stat = 'disabled' ) {
  // your code ..
}
```

so, if the second parameter (`$stat`) ommitted in URL, it will get `disabled` value